# Open NavigationLink from Local Notification in NavigationStack iOS17

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, swift-data, swiftui-navigationstack

The Notification provides the **uuid** corresponding to the **Item** saved in **SwiftData**.

**Goal** is to open the correct DetailItem View when I tap the notification.
How can I achieve this?

```
@Model
final class Item {
    @Attribute(.unique) var uuid: UUID
     ...
}
```

--

```
extension LocalNotificationManager: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
    
    guard let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["uuid"] as? Data else {
        print("No data found in notification userInfo")
        return
    }
    **What shall I do here ?**
    
}
```

--

```
struct ItemList: View {
@Query var items: [Item]
@State private var path = NavigationPath()

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, item in
                    NavigationLink(value: item) {
                        ItemButton(item: item, index: index)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }.navigationDestination(for: Item.self) { item in
            DetailItem(item: item)
        }
 }
```